# Automate Create tables procedure using Dynamic SQL using cursor or loop - PLSQL

Tags: sql, for-loop, plsql, cursor, create-table

Syntax: PL SQL
IDE: PL/SQL Developer

I'm attempting to generate 4 tables for each region using a series of Region codes.

***I understand that it may be more efficient to generate one table with all regions included and truncate and replace this table however based on the structure needed for use I am not allowed to this.***

The 4 regions come from a Specific table

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGION
FROM REGION_TABLE
;
```

What is the best method to generate this series of tables dynamically?

I've attempted to use a cursor and a loop but I am unsure of the method to integrate this cursor into the following Procedure.

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR C_REGION IS
       SELECT DISTINCT REGION FROM REGION_TABLE ;
BEGIN
     FOR L_IDX IN C_REGION
     LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(L_IDX.C_REGION);
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Using the cursor values above, how do I go about inserting these values into not only the table name used in the Create Table portion of the Sql statement but as a parameter in the where clause

```
-- 4 REGIONS  - NORTH SOUTH EAST WEST, 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SALES_ORDER_TBL_PROC
          (
          REGION IN VARCHAR2
          , RETURNCODE OUT NUMBER
          , ERROR_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2
          )
            IS 
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30);
  SQL_STR VARCHAR2;
  REGION_VAR VARCHAR;          
BEGIN 
  TABLE_NAME := 'SALES_COUNT_'||REGION_VAR;
  SQL_STR := 'CREATE TABLE '||TABLE_NAME||
             ' AS 
               (
               SELECT 
                      REGION
                          , COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_ID) AS NUM_MBR
                      FROM INCREMENTAL_SALES_TBL
                      WHERE 1=1
                          AND REGION = '||REGION_VAR||
                          'GROUP BY REGION)' 
               ;

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STR ;

         RETURNCODE := 0;

 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

         RETURNCODE := SQLCODE;

         ERROR_MESSAGE :='ERR:Creating/Altering table '||TABLE_NAME ||'-'||SQLERRM;
END;
/

BEGIN
     SALES_ORDER_TBL_PROC;
END;
```

Comment: creating tables seems like a one time job. why do you need a procedure for it?

Comment: These are reporting tables.  - company procedure simply needs to them to be rebuilt on the fly.

Comment: better truncate and load the data over

Comment: Understood - but there must be 4 unique tables, per the requirements given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting the DDL in a for loop?  I haven't tested the code below but it should at least put you on a path toward your goal, hopefully.

```
FOR rec IN (SELECT DISTINCT REGION FROM REGION_TABLE) LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'CREATE TABLE SALES_COUNT_' || UPPER(rec.region) || ' AS (
       SELECT REGION,
              COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_ID) AS NUM_MBR
         FROM INCREMENTAL_SALES_TBL
        WHERE REGION = ''' || rec.region || '''
        GROUP BY REGION)';
END LOOP;
```

I can't remember what the restrictions are when it comes to concatenation with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but if it's not working then it's possible to use bind variables and the USING clause.

Comment: This process worked very well and executed with a few tweeks.

Comment: This process worked very well and executed with ONE tweek. 1. The where clause should be WHERE REGION = '''|| REC.REGION|||''' Thank You

Comment: @BGDev ah, that gets me almost every time.  Glad you got it sorted out!  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it in the answer.